# Query Method: POST Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error - NextJS ^14.0.3 | Node 20

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to save orders with the post method but I always get a 500 Internal Server Error. Please help me figure out what's wrong.

Console

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/orders 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

This is the source code :

app/api/orders/route.js

```
"use server";

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import connect from "../../../utils/db";
import Order from "../../../models/Order";


export const POST = async (req) => {
  const newOrder = new Order(req.body);
  try {
    await connect();
    const savedOrder = await newOrder.save();
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(savedOrder), { status: 200 });
  } catch (err) {
    return new NextResponse("Database Error", { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

orders/page.jsx

```
"use client"


const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/api/orders", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId: session.user.id,
          products: products,
          total: totalPrice(),
          status: "pending",
          userEmail: session.user.email,
        }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      if (res.ok) {
        dispatch(resetCart());
        toast.success("Commande passée avec succès !");
        setTimeout(() => {
          router.push("/commandes");
        }, 1500);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("something wrong",err);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Visual Studio code and the code worked. Thanks

Comment: You should add this as a comment

Answer (score 0):

[from here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/error-handling)

> ### Handling Server Errors
>
> Next.js provides a static 500 page by default to handle server-side
> errors that occur in your application. You can also customize this
> page by creating a pages/500.js file.
>
> Having a 500 page in your application does not show specific errors to
> the app user.

in the `POST` handler's `catch` block

```
 } catch (err) {
    return new NextResponse("Database Error", { status: 500 });
  }
```

`console.log(err)` will tell you what is exact error message. it could be due to `connect` or `newOrder`. before saving the `newOrder` make sure it is a valid entry. Maybe client-side validation was not good enough so the user sent data without missing entry. you should examine `newOrder` as well. `console.log(newOrder)` if it is valid.

Seems like your `handleClick` does not throw an error otherwise, you would have this printed from its catch block `console.log("something wrong",err);`

Comment: I updated Visual Studio code and the code worked. Thanks